# jquery hover() IE7 & IE8

Tags: jquery, hover

Using jQuery 1.5.1
Tried this block of code in: head section as well as in line, in doc ready function as well as out. NOTHING makes it work, I'm stumped. It works in all other browsers.

What is supposed to happen is that when user hovers over a div with class "lsr" another div with display:none appears.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.lsr").hover(
            function() { $("#lsr").show(); },
            function() { $("#lsr").hide(); }
        );
    });
</script>
...
<div class="lsr"></div>

<div id="lsr""> Some Text appears </div>
```

ok.... so the ANSWER is that IE does NOT like the empty div. It apparently will not render it. The best solution I found was to use the following CSS on the empty div..... I tried adding padding and   none of that worked. What DOES work is to use the following CSS on the empty div.

```
.lsr {
  ...
  background-color: #fff;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity:0.0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing a type="text/javascript" attribute in your script-tag tho that is unlikely to fix the problem

Comment: [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hyAHP/) works fine in IE8. Are you including jQuery correctly? It sounds like a JavaScript error. It definitely needs to be **inside** the jQuery [document.ready](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) wrapper.

Comment: Is the security policy on IE blocking JavaScript? Do other JavaScript enabled sites work?

Comment: You can try the actual site ... I just added the link. It aint workin for me?

Comment: Also, I don't think it is my security policy because the jQuery based menu IS working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your `div.lsr` has no content, which would make it mighty hard to hover over (depending on your CSS)
- You have an extra `"` on `<div id="lsr"">`

If I fix these issues it works fine for me: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FSKBQ/)

**EDIT based on comments** IE has problems recognizing events on a `div` that has no content *and* that has `position: absolute`. To fix, try either using different CSS positioning, or adding content to the `div` (e.g. `&nbsp;`)

Comment: That div has a size and width on it off 100px;

Comment: Does the JSFiddle demo work for you? If so, can you pinpoint the differences between it and yours?

Comment: Your right it has something to do with empty divs. As you can see on the actual site, they are set to width & height of 100px, and they float over an image. If I add a single '.' to them when I hover over that it works. So... question is how to get around this in IE?

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't see that you had posted the link; that's helpful. I've run into this problem before with IE not recognizing a click event on an empty div with `position: absolute`. It seems like this is probably the same issue. Your options are probably to either add content (maybe an `&nbsp;`), or to style with something other than `position: absolute`.

Comment: Well thxs for the tip off anyway, the solution was not to use &nbsp; That didn't work. What did work was to use css to put a background color on the div and then set opacity to 0.

Answer (score 1):

document ready? It isn't in your sample code, but is it present in your own code?

```
$(function(){
   $("div.lsr").hover(
        function() { $("#lsr").show(); },
        function() { $("#lsr").hide(); }
    );
});
```

Comment: Yes it is, I was just being terse... actual code is now in question.